# Probability problem regarding rooks on a chessboard

Tags: probability, problem-solving

Eight rooks are placed in distinct squares of an 8 x 8 chessboard, with all possible replacements being equally likely. Find the probability that all the rooks are safe from one another.

Comment: You have also posted this question at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94733/probability-problem-regarding-rooks-on-a-chessboard - you should not copy the same question to multiple SE sites.

Comment: I am new to this site. I am sorry I didn't know that rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since rooks attack horizontally and vertically, you can't have a rook in the same row or column as another.

So in the first row, you place a rook. There are 8 possible places. In the next row you place a rook. It can't be in the same column as the other rook, so 7 possible places. So on and so on, to get $8!$ possible ways to place the rooks without them threatening one another.

That's your desired solution. You need to divide by all possible ways to place the rooks.

There are 64 spaces on a chess board and you need to place rooks in 8 of them. So it's just $64\choose8$.

That makes your answer $$\frac{8!}{64\choose8}$$

Comment: What I did was: I can place the first rook in (8 x 8) squares, and the next rook in (7 x 7) squares, and so on which makes the number of favourable cases = 8! x 8!. Can you please check where I am mistaken ?

Comment: @deatheatersay The problem is that you get repeats. Let's say you place your first rook in A1, your next rook in B2, etc.

A later placement puts the first rook in B2, the next rook in A1, then the rest the same. But the rooks are not unique, so you're counting the same solution twice.

What that approach comes up to is counting every possible way to place rooks with them not threatening each other, but WITH the order of placement being a factor and considered unique. Since there are 8 rooks, there are 8! orders you can place them per solution. That's where your extra 8! is coming from.

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot ! I got it.

Comment: @deatheatersay No problem. If this answers your question you could mark it as accepted :)

Comment: @deatheatersay Another perspective is, if you prefer the ratio of non-threatening moves (with repeats) to total moves (with repeats), instead of your calculation, which pitted no-repeats against repeats, then you've got: $$\frac {(8!)^2} {64! / 56!}.$$

Comment: How can 64 choose 8 be the total number of moves?  if its a 2x2 square and there are 2 rooks, then there would only be 4 choose 2, which is one.  There is more than one move though.

Comment: Why do we need to divide?  Wolfram Mathword http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RooksProblem.html (with a reference to a book)  claims that this is just n! (8! for 8x8 board),  which makes more sense to me. Oh, I see:  this is for the probability.

Answer (score 0):

Thought process:
- First rook can be placed in 64 squares.

- For the next rook the entire row and column of the first rook are off-limits, so the second rook has 64-16+1=49 squares available (add one to avoid double counting the square where the first rook was placed).

- repeat the same idea starting with 49 and add back double counted squares from the rows and columns of previous rooks already placed.

---

Calculating Probablity:

A:= placing 8 rooks without either of them capturing each other.

A_i:= placing the ith rook

first rook can be placed in           64 squares

second rook can be placed in 64-16+1= 49 squares

third rook can placed in 49-16+3=     36 squares

fourth rook can placed in 36-16+5=    25 squares

fifth rook can placed in 25-16+7=     16 squares

sixth rook can placed in 16-16+9=     9 squares

seventh rook can placed in 9-16+11=   4 squares

eighth rook can placed in 4-16+13=    1 square

By principle of counting |A| = |A_1|*|A_2|*|A_3|*|A_4|*|A_5|*|A_6|*|A_7|*|A_8| =
64*49*36*25*16*9*4*1 outcomes

P(A) = |A| / |S| = 64*49*36*25*16*9*4*1 / 64*63*62*61*60*59*58*57