# Placing rooks in a $8\times8$ chess board , Another way

Tags: probability

I know [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/764776/831100) for this problem and for simplicity you can see that below:

> Since rooks attack horizontally and vertically, you can't have a rook in the same row or column as another.So in the first row, you place a rook. There are 8 possible places. In the next row you place a rook. It can't be in the same column as the other rook, so 7 possible places. So on and so on, to get $8!$ possible ways to place the rooks without them threatening one another.
> That's your desired solution. You need to divide by all possible ways to place the rooks.
> There are 64 spaces on a chess board and you need to place rooks in 8 of them. So it's just $64\choose8$.
> That makes your answer $$\frac{8!}{64\choose8}$$

I tried **another way** for solving this but I got another answer!
Lets assume we want to place each rook sequentially so for the first one we can choose 8 columns and 8 rows and we have:$$8\times8$$For the second one we can choose now 7 columns and 7 rows so:$$7\times7$$And if we continue this process to the end we will get$$\frac{(8!)^2}{64\choose8}$$
Why my answer is different?

Comment: You're over counting, for example let's say you put the first rook on a1 and second on b2, you can get the same configuration if you put the first rook on b2 and second on a1.

Comment: That is because in the second case, you are also distinguishing between rooks so for example rook labeled $1$ is in row $1$ or rook labeled $2$ is in row $1$ are different arrangements. Your denominator will have to be multiplied by $8!$ to label rooks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first result is correct.

Consider the $2×2$ case. There are six ways to place the rooks and two of these have the rooks at peace. That matches

$(2!)^\color{blue}1/\binom{4}{2}.$

The permutation where the rooks are at the upper left and the lower right is the same whether you put the first rook on the lower right and the second on the upper left or vice versa. To count it only once you need to fix the ordering of rows (or of columns). The same applies for the second "correct" permutation on the other diagonal.

So you should count only for a fixed ordering of rows to avoid double counting or, for the full board, $8!$-counting.